# With react-select, select multiple items matching search simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using [`react-select`](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) to display a searchable drop-down list of items, of which the user can select multiple items.  My list is quite long and the user will often wish to multi-select many items which match the same filter string, which is a bit of a tedious procedure because each time you select an item the dropdown disappears and you need to re-type the search.

For example, the following sandbox has a `react-select` which lists lots of apples and cheeses.  In order to select all the Apples, one would have to keep typing "Apple" and choosing one apple at a time.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2l99lry5p

Coming from desktop UI background, I naturally want to be able to type a search query and press `Ctrl-A` to select all of the matching search results and add them to my list, or `Ctrl-Click` to cherry pick multiple items from the matching set.  But as far as I can tell there's no support for any hotkey like this in react-select.

Does the `react-select` API have any way that I can implement a "select all" hotkey which would select everything that matches the current search filter (or even an explicit "select all matches" button on the page would be fine)?  I cannot see any programmatic way to get access to the set of objects which match the filter.  Is this something that I would need to fork `react-select` to implement or is it possible to do this via the existing API somehow?

Comment: The react-select lib, it seems, [does not provide special API to select all currently displayed items](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js#L78-L229). I think, in order to solve this problem, you want to either fork and adjust the component itself or build your own higher-order component that adds this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

**React Select** has built-in props that can be used to prevent the menu from closing on select and persist the search string.

First prevent the menu from closing on select by setting `closeMenuOnSelect` to `false`.

Then `onInputChange` store the search string in `state` if the action equals `'input-change'`.

Setting `inputValue` to `this.state.value` will persist the search string in the input field.

```
class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        };
    }
    handleInputChange = (value, e) => {
        if (e.action === 'input-change') {
            this.setState({value});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Select
                isMulti
                name="colors"
                options={options.map(x => MakeOption(x))}
                className="basic-multi-select"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                /* added these props */
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                inputValue={this.state.value}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

*Updated sandbox:* https://codesandbox.io/s/yvmzx6pn6z

Comment: This is definitely an improvement, but still not very easy to select all of the apples, it requires me to click each search result.    I was able to mod my sample to where the `onInputChange` handler prints the list of matching results to the console and trying to make a button which will "select all matches" by pushing the results via the `state` back into the `value` prop of the react-select, perhaps will post a self-answer if that works out.  One trouble I have is the the `onInputChange` happens before it populates the matching results, and there doesn't seem to be a post-filter event.

Comment: This answer was really helpful. I Just added a OnBlur event to the Select component to clear the inputValue after the items were chosen

Answer (score 2):

I hacked up something that kind of does what I want but is quite ugly:

https://codesandbox.io/s/j7453qrmv

To use:

- Try searching "apple", then press "Add all matching items to selection"

The approach:

- As @wdm mentioned, there's a `onInputChanged` you can hook in to.
- In `onInputChanged`, get the matching items store them in the state of the component
- I add a button near the `Select` which allows the user to choose to copy the matching set of items into another state variable `chosenItems`
- The `react-select` `Select` component has a `value` property that you can provide to programmatically choose the items.  I pass `state.chosenItems` in to this.

This works but there were many things that make this a pain:

- The `onInputChanged` handler gets called before the items matching the filter appear.  I attempted to grab the matching items by DOM queries but it did not work because `onInputChanged` is too early.  So rather than relying on `react-select`'s filtering logic, I'm replicating the filtering logic in the `onInputChanged` handler.  This is not great as there could be a discrepancy between my filtering logic and the displayed list of matching items.
- Whenever you click after typing a search, the `react-select` clears the search, which invokes the `onInputChanged` event again. So by clicking on the custom "Add All Matching Items" button, it removes the filter, clearing the list, invoking `onInputChanged` and setting the state with a new list of matching items.  To deal with this I needed to have a `previousMatchingOptions` state variable which keeps track of the matching items from the previous call to `onInputChanged`.  This seems like a terrible hack.
- Likewise, I attempted to hide/show my "Select All Matching Items" button based on whether there were currently more than one item that matches the search, but I was similarly thwarted by timing issues.  I attempted to hack around this but kept getting caught up in corner cases.
- The UI I came up with for "Select All Matching Items" doesn't feel integrated with the `react-select` very well. It would be nicer if it was part of their component rather than beside it.
- By using the `values` property of the `Select` component, you are bypassing the component's internal management of its state, so the normal way of adding, removing, and clearing items does not work without reimplementing all that in a custom `onChange` handler which modifies the `state.chosen` which is passed to `values`.  Managing this myself seems also less than desirable.

So, I have a solution, but if someone has something has a suggestion that is much cleaner and/or simpler I would be happy to hear it!

It seems like forking the control and doing these changes internal to the component might be the better way to go.

- In my `onInputChanged` I attempted to get the matching search results directly from the DOM using some `getElementsByClassName` hackery, though this approach did not work because the `onInputChanged`

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way of implementing a "Select All" option is overriding React-Select component with a custom component. For that you first need to import it as

```
import { default as ReactSelect } from 'react-select';
```

then create a custom component which defines a new Property named "allowSelectAll", and selects all the options when this property is set to 'true'.

```
const Select = props => {
    if (props.allowSelectAll) {
        if (props.value && (props.value.length === props.options.length)) {
            return (
                <ReactSelect
                    {...props}
                    value={[props.allOption]}
                    onChange={selected => props.onChange(selected.slice(1))}
                />
            );
        }

        return (
            <ReactSelect
                {...props}
                options={[props.allOption, ...props.options]}
                onChange={selected => {
                    if (
                        selected.length > 0 &&
                        selected[selected.length - 1].value === props.allOption.value
                    ) {
                        return props.onChange(props.options);
                    }
                    return props.onChange(selected);
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    return <ReactSelect {...props} />;
};

Select.propTypes = {
    options: PropTypes.array,
    value: PropTypes.any,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    allowSelectAll: PropTypes.bool,
    allOption: PropTypes.shape({
        label: PropTypes.string,
        value: PropTypes.string
    })
};

Select.defaultProps = {
    allOption: {
        label: "Select all",
        value: "*"
    }
};
```

> **Note:** You can simply copy and paste the above given code and it will work absolutely fine.

And once that is done you can simply use the new 'Select' component with 'allowSelectAll' property set to true.

```
<Select allowSelectAll={true} isMulti={true} isSearchable={true} options={options} />
```

Comment: You also need to import **PropTypes**

Comment: I was not able to copy-paste this code and get it to work.  But if I understand the intent of your code I don't think it solves my original question, because it "selects all" (from the original set), whereas I was looking for a solution to "select all matches" (everything that matches the current search filter).  FYI I provided an answer to my own question below which is similar to your answer (add a "select all matches" button to the control) but wasn't too satisfied with my result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filterOption` function like this:

```
<select
  options={[{label: 'test', value: 1, customData: 'bla blub test'}]}
  filterOption={(option, filter) => {
    const { customData } = option.customData;

    if(customData.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }} />
```

Hope this will help you :)